# counting onto functions and similar problems

Tags: combinatorics

The problem : How many ways are there to distribute 10 different toys to 3 children such that each child gets at least one toy? is same as counting onto functions from a set of 10 elements to a set of 3 elements. I am trying to understand how to apply this idea of counting onto function if the original problem is changed to (each child gets at least 2 or 3 toys). Are there any direct formula for it? thanks

Comment: I would probably approach via inclusion-exclusion.  Count how many ways if we don't care if someone is without a toy, how many ways there are such that at least one child doesn't get a toy and how many ways there are such that at least two children don't get a toy.  Alternatively, approaching using [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and then rearranging the children would answer the original question but wouldn't give much intuition for answering the more general one.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have to calculate number of onto function from

$f:\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,120\right\}\rightarrow \left\{a,b,c\right\}.$

So Total number of onto function $=$ Total number of function- (number of into function)

So here Total number of function $ \displaystyle = 3^{10}$ and Total number of into function $ = 2^{10}\times 3-3$

So Total number of onto function $ = 3^{10}-\left(3\times 2^{10}-3\right)$